# Is it possible to run docker engine without frequent sudo in a manner as secure as docker desktop?

Tags: docker

Does running docker "engine" require `sudo`'ing constantly during development? Is that what you are doing? Do you `sudo -i` when operating docker? Or do you set a timer on sudo? Is there a safe way to operate it more handily e.g. enabling a key/pass manager?

*Background*

Having followed the Docker website's nudge to install "desktop" (even the "engine" URL endpoint links to desktop, albeit also the engine), I have encountered a few situations making me consider using the engine only on my linux:

- constantly being prompted a [passphrase](https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/115) for desktop upon initializing a [credential](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/102) pass with GPG - 'fixed' with seahorse/pass.
- requiring `sudo` if using engine - can be fixed with a [group](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user) albeit this is [risky](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743509/530603).
- running two docker contexts: default (engine) and desktop-linux - can be [switched](https://serverfault.com/questions/1128587/change-the-docker-context-in-docker-desktop) but still prompts `sudo`.
- engine and desktop showing two different lists upon `docker context ls` - may be [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75134896/docker-context-ls-and-sudo-docker-context-ls-dont-have-same-setting-options) by creating a root user context for the same docker endpoint.

This has made me more aware of the differences, described somewhat in the docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#what-is-the-difference-between-docker-desktop-for-linux-and-docker-engine) and [forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/difference-between-docker-desktop-and-docker-engine/124612).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### 1. Not as with docker on the host machine as root

Docker desktop is more secure (only) because it runs in a [virtual machine](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/).  This means that a compromised user with docker-desktop access can only do damage to docker containers and and your docker engine, not the whole of your host system.

So a docker daemon running as root on the host system will always have this security vulnerability.  That's just the nature of it.

At least this, running as a root daemon on the host without a VirtualMachine container, this will always drop you into a root terminal:

```bash
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host ubuntu:latest nsenter -at 1
```

---

###### 2. Docker Engine (no Desktop) in a Virtual Machine

There's nothing stopping you running docker in a virtual machine yourself, although you'd need to work through the semantics of making bind mounts work.

###### 3. Non-root Docker

Your other option is to run docker as a non-root user.  This should mean that docker itself has much less access to your system but it will add limitations to what you can run inside docker.  See here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

> - Only the following storage drivers are supported:
>
>   - overlay2 (only if running with kernel 5.11 or later, or Ubuntu-flavored kernel)
>   - fuse-overlayfs (only if running with kernel 4.18 or later, and fuse-overlayfs is installed)
>   - btrfs (only if running with kernel 4.18 or later, or ~/.local/share/docker is mounted with user_subvol_rm_allowed mount option)
>     -vfs
> - Cgroup is supported only when running with cgroup v2 and systemd. See Limiting resources.
> - Following features are not supported:
>
>   - AppArmor
>   - Checkpoint
>   - Overlay network
>   - Exposing SCTP ports
> - To use the ping command, see Routing ping packets.
> - To expose privileged TCP/UDP ports (< 1024), see Exposing privileged ports.
> - IPAddress shown in docker inspect is namespaced inside RootlessKit's network namespace. This means the > - IP address is not reachable from the host without nsenter-ing into the network namespace.
> - Host network (docker run --net=host) is also namespaced inside RootlessKit.
> - NFS mounts as the docker "data-root" is not supported. This limitation is not specific to rootless mode.

###### 4. Make a dedicated, password-protected docker user

Make a dedicated user that you access with

```shell
sudo -iu docker-admin-user
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks, Philip. Also for pointing out rootless mode. May I ask also what you do yourself then - do you `sudo` a whole lot? Use `podman` instead? Run "engine" in a VM with `bind mounts`? etc. :-)

Comment: If I'm totally honest, I just keep myself in the `docker` group and live with the risk ([see xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1200/)). A half way pont might be to make a dedicated user that you access with `sudo -iu docker-admin-user`.  That way there's limited risk of rogue software gaining access to that user with no password of it's own, but you are not forced to keep typing `sudo` over and over or re-entering your password.  Podman will have similar risks.

Comment: Right, so at least no desktop-linux AFAICT. And your risk calculus, I take it, is that if a hacker were able to operate `docker` without `sudo` worse things would probably happen. That makes sense.